# Linked table insert without cursors

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, cursor

**tl;dr**

Using SQLServer 2005 (the minimum we support), is it possible to copy data from linked tables without using a cursor?

**Details**

I have two tables with the following rough structure...

```
dbo.[ParentTable]
[ItemId]  [UserId]  [Details]
1         1         'One'
2         1         'Two'

dbo.[ChildTable]
[ChildId]  [ItemId]  [Details]
1          1         'One A'
2          1         'One B'
3          2         'Two A'
4          2         'Two B'
```

`ParentTable.ItemId` is PK with identity(1,1)
`ChildTable.ChildId` is PK with identity(1,1)
`ChildTable.ItemId` is FK to `ParentTable.ItemId`

At the moment if I need to copy all data for `UserId=1` to `UserId=2` I have to do the following...

```
DECLARE @ItemId INT, @NewItemId INT

DECLARE [ParentCursor] CURSOR FOR
SELECT [ItemId]
FROM [ParentTable]
WHERE [UserId] = 1

OPEN [ParentCursor]
FETCH NEXT FROM [ParentCursor] INTO @ItemId
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO [ParentTable] ([UserId], [Details])
  SELECT 2, [Details]
  FROM [ParentTable]
  WHERE [ItemId] = @ItemId

  SET @NewItemId = @@IDENTITY

  INSERT INTO [ChildTable] ([ItemId], [Details]
  SELECT @NewItemId, [Details]
  FROM [ChildTable]
  WHERE [ItemId] = @ItemId

  FETCH NEXT FROM [ParentCursor] INTO @ItemId
END
CLOSE [ParentCursor]
DEALLOCATE [ParentCursor]
```

This achieves the desired outcome of...

```
dbo.[ParentTable]
[ItemId]  [UserId]  [Details]
1         1         'One'
2         1         'Two'
3         2         'One'
4         2         'Two'

dbo.[ChildTable]
[ChildId]  [ItemId]  [Details]
1          1         'One A'
2          1         'One B'
3          2         'Two A'
4          2         'Two B'
5          3         'One A'
6          3         'One B'
7          4         'Two A'
8          4         'Two B'
```

Is there a simpler way of doing this without using a cursor?

(Note, I have tried creating a http://sqlfiddle.com but I simply cannot get it to use a cursor correctly. Something to do with delimiters, but I can't figure it out.)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this...

```
declare @olduser int = 1, @newuser int = 2
set transaction isolation level serializable
begin tran

    declare @max int 
    select @max = MAX(itemid) from ParentTable -- as a marker for new records

    -- insert all the parents
    insert ParentTable (userid, details) 
    select @newuser, details from ParentTable where userid=@olduser order by itemid


    insert ChildTable (itemid, details)             
    select newid, details from ChildTable child
        inner join 
    (
            -- join the old parents to the new parents
    select p2.itemid as oldid, p1.itemid as newid   
    from 
        (select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by itemid) rn from parenttable where itemid>@max) p1
        inner join 
        (select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by itemid) rn from parenttable where userid=@olduser and itemid<=@max) p2
            on p1.rn = p2.rn
    ) oldparents
        on child.itemid = oldparents.oldid
commit tran
```

Comment: Wow - going to take me while to wrap my smaller-than-average brain around that one!  Thanks podiluska

Comment: @freefaller It relies on details in ParentTable being unique within a user.

Comment: Unfortunately that cannot be guaranteed... although there are a lot more columns in both the [Parent] and the [Child] tables.  I will have a play

Comment: @freefaller I've improved it so that is no longer the case.